# JavaScript: how to test if clearInterval function is true or false

Tags: javascript

I've a little question i'd like to test if my `clearInterval(playfunction)` is true of false and I tought it would work like this

```
if(clearInterval(play)==true){

    //do this 1

    }
    else{

    //do this 2

    }
```

But it dosnt work like this...what did I do wrong?

Kind Regards,
and thanks for help!

Comment: Why would it ever be `false` and what do you want to do with this information?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469339/checking-whether-clearinterval-has-been-called

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`clearInterval` doesn't return anything. It will always be `undefined` and never `true` or `false`.

Comment: I've a hover function and I just wanna test if the play stop if i hover a div

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to test with the result of `clearInterval`? That function has no return-type.